# How to find font and colour for each text in Python web scraping?

Tags: python, html, css, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I wrote a Python scraper that can scrape text from websites and now I am in the process of labelling font and size.
For example the CSS is:

```
td{ font-family:Arial; font-size:9pt; }
hr { height:1px; }
.currency { color:#000099; }
```

HTML:

```
<td align="left">
<font class="currency">USD</font>
"3.20"
</td>
```

My desired output:

```
{
"text": ["USD", "3.20"],
"font": ["Arial", "Arial"],
"colours": ["#000099", "#000000"],
}
```

Is there any way I can do this with BeautifulSoup or regex?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some thoughts I came up with a solution, although its not elegant it worked fine:
1. Parse css using regex and construct a dictionary with classes and styles
2. Iterate through the dictionary and use beautifulsoup select method to inject labelling to the html string, for example:

```
original:
>>> <b>some text</b>
inject labels:
bs4_object.string = bs4_object.text + label
>>> <b>some[[bold]] text[[bold]]</b>
```

3. Use bs4 to extract all the text, then parse the labels into a list

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any way I can do this with **BeautifulSoup or regex**?

Yes and no, but it's probably more work than its worth, and not bulletproof, so I would lean towards no. If you are using `beautifulsoup` alone and want to know what styles are applied to an element as if you were using a browser, then it's hard.

You need to add some other tools in the mix, such as a headless browser.

## Keeping your setup

### HTML + CSS

First, some background.

`HTML` is the document itself, the one with the information, computer program-parsable, and transformable. And this is what you have so far with your program.

`CSS` is just something made for the browsers and for humans. Its purpose is to make the document prettier, clearer and easier to use. To get a broader view of how `CSS` is used by the browser, check this [How `CSS` works MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/First_steps/How_CSS_works). This means that the styles are loaded separately and applied "at runtime", in the browser. There's also at least three different way to specify styles on an element (separate documents, inline, etc).

### Scraping

I suppose you use something like `requests` to download the page, then feed it to `beautifulsoup`, and then pick whatever data you need from there. To use that diagram from the article, what you have are the first three boxes from the top row, i.e. without loading or parsing the `CSS`, and without displaying the page.

This also goes for any DOM manipulation that happens in the browser after the page is loaded, e.g. content loaded dynamically via API calls, or any `JS` that modifies the page — you won't be able to catch those in the `requests`-`beautifulsoup` pipeline.

So, out of the box, there doesn't seem to be a way of grabbing an element with `bs`, and querying what styles are applied to it, because that's not its scope. What you can do is to get the styling separately and make sense of it on your own.

### DIY

First, you can get the element's `style` attribute (`td['style']`), and parse that for the fonts. Note that there's a bunch of ways of specifying that, too, e.g. `font: italic 1.2em "Fira Sans", serif;`, `font: small-caps bold 24px/1 sans-serif;`, `font-family: 'Fira Sans', serif; font-size: 1.2em;`. But then, there's also the *cascading* part of the `CSS`, which means that an element's parent can apply styles to its children.

Then there's also `<style>` tags in the document, as well as `<link rel="stylesheet">`.

The point is that this is work done by a browser (and a hard task at that!), you would be partly replicating it, and there's other things you could use.

## Headless browser

The thing for the job has a name and this is it. What it means is that it's a browser implementation without the actual GUI, and which you can use programatically, through an API. This makes it great for testing websites, for instance, as well as scraping pages that have dynamic content, or for which you need styling info.

I can't recommend any, having not used any myself, but this should be enough to get you started.